# Are there any recommendable books or websites to learn grammar myths?

Tags: discussion

There are many methods of phrasing one's words that are not told in a standard grammar book, especially in oral English. If there is a book or website about this kind of myths, it would be very convenient for English learners.

Do you have any books or websites other than stackexchange to recommend?

Comment: we wouldn't really call such things "myths", but speaking with native speakers and reading/watching content made by native speakers is probably the best way of learning such things

Comment: @Esther That way, we learners can't tell whether it's common among native speakers or just that very individual's habit.

Comment: ask questions here if it seems unusual to you! Besides, colloquial speech varies *widely* across different locations/areas/communities/etc. There is no one way of speaking that sounds natural to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Esther mentioned, colloquial speech varies quite widely even between populations in the same geographic area.  For written American English, however, I can heartily recommend *Garner's Modern English Usage*, which contains a section on what he terms "Superstitions", of which split infinitives are one example.  The section on Superstitions only takes up two pages of a dictionary-length book, but he treats other similar subjects at some length, such as elegant variation, which he pointedly renames as "Inelegant Variation".